# Letting a Text Copy itself along a path until the end. (Indesign)

Tags: adobe-indesign, text-on-path

Ich am having trouble finding an elegant solution.
Here are the assumptions: 
I have a path along which I want to have a text (Company Name + Spacing Element)
I want that text to copy itself until the path ends. 
I don't want to copy the text by hand along that path, because if I format the Text differently I want it to fill with Text automatically without having to erase overflow text because i have less space, or recopy because suddenly i have more space. Also it would be neat that if there is ever a change of the repeating text element, that i just have to go into one place change it and have it apply automatically.
I have tried it with text variables, but i seem to be stuck on how to achieve that effect. 
It will look somewhat like this: 
Sample Text: 
"- Super Cool Company -   "
and the aim is to have something like this along the path:

"- Super Cool Company -   - Super Cool Company -   - Super Cool Company -   - Super Cool Company -   - Super Cool Company -   - Super Cool Company -   - Super Cool Company -   - Super Cool Company -  "

The path will be along the edges of a shopping bag (Left to Bottom to Right)
I want the text to flow along those edges. 
I hope my question is understandable ! :) 
Best wishes 
Roxi

Answer (score 3):

Goto Illustrator. You can make your text a pattern brush. Outline it and drag to the brushes collection. Use scissors to split the path, if needed.

[image]

After outlining you can add any graphic shape as the separating element. Here nothing is added.

Comment: +1 for a solution; +2 (if I could) for making a shopping bag look like an upside-down popsicle. :-D

Comment: danke ! Das wäre mein Ausweg gewesen, dachte es geht vielleicht in Indesign.